# Avoiding copy-pasting in visible range

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to avoid copy-pasting in my code by simply referring to other range.

```
   VisibleRowsCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(3, Range(FromTable & "[" & FlagColumn & "]"))

   Dim DestinationRange As Range, SourceRange As Range

   Set DestinationRange = Sheets("Sht1").ListObjects(ToTable).ListColumns(ColumnSplit(0)).Range
   Set SourceRange = Sheets("Sht2").ListObjects(FromTable).ListColumns(ColumnSplit(1)).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

   DestinationRange.Cells(lastCell, 1).Resize(SourceRange.Count, 1).Value = SourceRange
```

I get correct number of new rows but all the values are all only equal to first row of visible range.

I use ListObjects columns as destination and Source ranges if it is important to know.

Comment: `SourceRange.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` doesn't look right. Think we need more info.

Comment: How are they defined DestinationRange, VisibleRowsCount and SourceRange? Depends on how VisibleRowsCount is working, they will not work on filtered ranges. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357806/row-count-for-visible-cells-only

Comment: more code added

Comment: Can you add more code so that we can have [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?